# ImageView inside scrollview (Android)

Tags: android, xml

I can't seem to be able to set my `imageView` to fill up the whole space (view) of my button. I have button that has a white space as background.

Please take a look at **my sample**

[image]

**My code:**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom" >

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scroll"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                     <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/imageView21"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                 android:src="@drawable/bg_shkaf" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I agree with @Tufan, post more details...

Comment: Have you try to set scale type "fitXY"  ?

Comment: @ShivamVerma he/she already use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

Comment: Well, he/she better read the comments in that case.

Comment: @ShivamVerma okay, sorry I don't read comments

Comment: @HareshChhelana fitXY not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `android:fillViewport="true"` for scroll view and change `ImageView` scale type to  `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom" >

                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scroll"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                         <ImageView
                     android:id="@+id/imageView21"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:scaleType="fitXY"
                     android:src="@drawable/bg_shkaf" />

                        </RelativeLayout>



        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @mzb86604 Do vote up as you have enough reputation :)